Cookies not being set in frontend React js but works in Postman
I am making a full stack ecommerece website but when i login the backend send an object containing token , success message and user details but the thing to access the other function i have made an isVerified function which gets the token from cookie and checks it , i have tested all the function in Postman and they were working but in frontend they are not working as they keep saying req.cookie.token undefined
 I want that token to be stored in cookie in frontend and be accesible

Tech used is React Js , Express js Browser is Chrome
I have tried everything pls someone help me out
I have tried using secure to remove , set to http from true to false
set the app with cors with credentials true , 
Added the Cors configuration
Added the way i am sending the token
Should i push my project to github so that u guyz can clone it
I have an another approach to do the verify
but i want to go it in backend not in frontend
so guyz pls help me out
   // Code 
   Login function in Frontend
    
   
       const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
               e.preventDefault();
               const user = { email, password };
               const response = await login(user);
               if (response.error) {
                   console.error('Login error:', response.error);
       
               } else {
       
                   Cookies.set('token', response.token, { expires: 7, sameSite: 'lax' });
                   setUser(response.user);
                   console.log('Login successful:', response);
                   navigate('/');
               }
       
           };
//   Auth middleware in backend 
   const isVerified = async (req, res, next) => {
     const token = req.cookies.token;
     console.log(token);
   
     if (!token) {
       return next(new ErrorHandler("Login first to access this resource", 401));
     }
     const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
     req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
     next();
   };
   // Util send token function
   // Creating a token and sending it in a cookies
   const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
     const token = user.getJwtToken();
   
     const options = {
       expires: new Date(
         Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
       ),
       httpOnly: false,
     };
   
     res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
       success: true,
       token,
       user,
     });
   };
   module.exports = sendToken;

app.use(
 cors({
   origin: "http://localhost:3000",
   credentials: true,
 })
);

    res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
       success: true,
       token,
       user,
     });
   };


Is your frontend and backend hosted on the same domain (or subdomain)?

the error is resolved thanks anyways

@Lokeshchauhan Hey can you tell me how did you solve the problem? I'm facing a similar problem

Here is updated list of possible solutions.

Check if you include creditential in your request. For example, if you use axios

    axios.get('http://your-server-url.com/api/data', {
      withCredentials: true
    });


Ensure that the options variable passed to res.cookie() contains the appropriate settings for your cookie, such as maxAge, httpOnly, secure, etc.

const options = {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // expires in 7 days
  httpOnly: true, // cookie is accessible only through HTTP(S) request, not JavaScript
  secure: true, // cookie will only be sent over HTTPS
  sameSite: 'none' // allows cross-site requests
};


Make sure your application is running in a secure context (HTTPS) if you're setting the secure flag on the cookie.
Just in case. Check your server logs and browser console for any errors related to setting the cookie or CORS policies. They might provide more specific information about what's going wrong.

And also you don't have to set your cookies manually on client because the server does it for you including cookie in your response. So you don't actually need this line.
Cookies.set('token', response.token, { expires: 7, sameSite: 'lax' });

Hope this will help you.

Credentials include can u elaborate ,  and no there is no cookie shown in appplication Tab i am just really frustated this is my first freelance project

Can you update description and show how exactly you send cookie from server? If there are no Cookies in DevTools, so it most likely a server problem. Also please add your CORS configuration

done added cors config and how i am sending token

Still Didn't work

Glad to help. I wish you a pleasant experience in learning.
